# How to Parse the URL using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following url's:

```
/html5/test2,
/html5/test1
```

I need to get the value after html5, in this case test2, test1. How to achieve this using jquery?

Comment: Do you mean you want to read the URL of the page you are currently on, or do you mean you have two strings that just happen to be URLs?

Comment: I rushed too much, thank you for the notice! I removed the flagged comment. @JavaScript

Comment: You need to show more examples,otherwise it is not jquery's question

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code for getting the last string of your url.

```
<%      

        String modifiedPath1 = request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri").toString(); //services/order_taking
        int lastIndex = modifiedPath1.lastIndexOf("/");
        modifiedPath1 = modifiedPath1.substring(lastIndex,modifiedPath1.length());
        modifiedPath1=modifiedPath1.replaceAll("/","");
        System.out.println("the modified path" +modifiedPath1);

    %>
```

Comment: In which of the three categories consisting of javascript, jquery and html does this one fall?

Comment: you put inside your jsp page.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need jQuery. Get the pathname `window.location.pathname` and use `split()`.

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
var value = pathname.split("/html5/")[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as the following using [.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop).

```
"/html5/test2".split("/").pop(); // test2
```

Here is what you'd do:

```
var pathPart = location.pathname.split("/").pop();
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `substring` and `lastIndexOf` or `split` method from JavaScript.

**1.**

```
var url = "/html5/test2";
console.log(url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/")+1,url.length)); //test2
```

**2.**

```
var urlStr = "/html5/test2".split("/");
urlStr[urlStr.length-1]; //test2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `split` function as follow:

```
var str = "/html5/test1";
var test = str.split("/")[2];
console.log(test); //gives test1
```